# Does using Windows Live Mail 2012 pose a security risk?

Tags: windows, security, email-client, windows-live-mail, vulnerabilities

As far as I know, Windows Live Mail didn't receive updates since 2012. From [CVE Details](https://www.cvedetails.com/), I have found [CVE-2008-3068](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2008-3068/). But I don't know if it has been fixed since that time or not.

I have come across [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/all/windows-live-mail-is-a-big-security-risk/925695c4-b725-4e9f-bcb9-bf8e8ca9ab17#:%7E:text=My%20Opinion%20of%20Using%20WLM,This%20thread%20is%20locked), but it seems lacking evidence supporting the claim made (*"Windows Live Mail is a big security risk"*).

So, my question is: Does using Windows Live Mail (as of September, 2022) pose any security risk other than the one mentioned above? If yes, can you provide some evidence?

Comment: It has not been updated because it is out of support and from an out of support operating system. Not much else to say

Comment: Still using it and have no security issues.

Comment: @Moab Can you use it with Gmail?

Comment: Never tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any program that interacts with content from unknown, possibly malicious actors, like a mail client, needs to be updated from time to time. WLM is out of support. Possibly, it has vulnerabilities - but that won't be researched, since it is out of support - as simple as that. Windows Live Mail reached its End of Life on June 30, 2016.

It does not imply that it is a huge risk, no. But surely, it is not recommendable to still use it.

Please note that WLM is not windows live messenger! https://www.cvedetails.com/product/14449/?q=windows+live+mail is the page for it.

Comment: You have two questions. Bernd has answered one of them. There's a reason we require questions to have ONE question in them. This is a good example why. Edit your question to focus on the actual and single question you want answered.

Comment: @music2myear Edited.

Comment: Zak, that cve is for wlm 2008, not 2012. 2012 is unaffected.